# JPA Join table with multiple columns for different collections

Tags: hibernate, jpa, multiple-columns, one-to-many

I have the following db structure (security_margin is One to Many to security_margin_service_model):

[image]

I Have the following code in a jpa Entity called **SecurityMargin** where i try to model a join table for the three entities (security_margin, model and service)

```
@Column
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "security_margin_service_model",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "margin_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "service_id")})
List<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();

@Column
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "security_margin_service_model",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "margin_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "model_id")})
List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
```

When i persist the entity SecurityMargin for I would expect to see something like this:

| margin_id | service_id | model_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e7f90b99-674c-4975-b5c0-4525d2587e12 | 67cabe71-2a77-4bab-b6d4-35980e626123 | 48 |

and instead I get them stored in two different rows.

| margin_id | service_id | model_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e7f90b99-674c-4975-b5c0-4525d2587e12 |  | 48 |
| e7f90b99-674c-4975-b5c0-4525d2587e12 | 67cabe71-2a77-4bab-b6d4-35980e626123 |  |

Not sure how to tell hibernate not to call the insert twice in this case...I'm lost!

Any help really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are getting is expected since you have two independent collections which just happen to use the same table for their mapping. Let's assume you have more than one service and one model then that can lead to a lot of combinations:
ServiceMargin (sm_id1):
service: [ 1, 2 ]
model: [ 1 ]

should it result in

```
[ sm_id1, 1, 1 ]
[ sm_id1, 2, null ]
```

or

```
[ sm_id1, 1, null ]
[ sm_id1, 2, 1 ]
```

or

```
[ sm_id1, 1, null ]
[ sm_id1, 2, null ]
[ sm_id1, null, 1 ]
```

The simplest way to achieve what you are asking for is to create one more entity that will be mapped to the `security_margin_service_model` table and have a single pair of `Service`/`Model` in it. Then instead of having two collections in `SecurityMargin` you'd have a single collection of this new entity.

But that only makes sense if there's some sort of relation between the service and model pair saved within the same `SecurityMargin`. Otherwise, consider having separate tables `security_margin_service` and `security_margin_model`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes that is the solution I'm going to implement, though I hoped there was some magic tric around to avoid it :-)
Yes, the relationship between service and model doesn't allow to use different join tables.

Comment: I was still wondering if it's not better to create a @Query "insert" for the ServiceModel table instead. When persisting SecurityMargin calling also that insert in a transaction.